# connect a database with externals tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I never made something similar .

I have a system and i need to relate my data with external data  (in another database).
My preference is get these data and create my own tables, but in this case when the other dbs are updated my personal tables will be obsolete.

So, basically i need to synchronize my tables with external tables, or just get the external data values.

I don't have any idea how i can connect and relate data from ten external databases.

I need to check if an user is registered in another websites basically.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am crrently doing something similar.

Easiset way I found is to pull the data in,  though I do bi-directional syncronisation in my project you haven't mentionned this so I imagine it's a data pull you are aiming for .

You need to have user accounts on the other servers, and the account needs to be created with an ip instead of 'localhost'.  You will connect from your end through mysql client using the ip of distant host instead of the ususal localhost.

see [this page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0540__Privilege/Giveanonlocaluserpermissionsonthedatabaseforusewithremoteclients.htm) for a bit more info.

If, like me you have to interface to different db server types, I recommend using a database abstraction library to ease the managing of data in a seamless way across different sql servers.  I chose Zend_db components, used standaline with Zend_config as they Support MySQL and MSSQL.

**UPDATE - Using a proxy DB to access mission critical data**

Depending on the scope of your project, if the data is not accessible straight from remote database,  there are different possibilities. To answer your comment I will tell you how we resolved the same issues on the current project I am tied to.  The client has a big MSSQL database that is is business critical application, accounting, invoicing, inventory, everything is handled by one big app tied to MSSQL. My mandate is to install a CRM , and synchronise the customers of his MSSQL mission-critical-app into the CRM, running on MySQL by the way.

I did not want to access this data straight from my CRM, this CRM should not ever touch their main MSSQL DB, I certainly am not willing to take the responsibility of something ever going wrong down the line, even though in theory this should not happen, in practice theory is often worthless.  The recommandation I gave (and was implemented) was to setup a proxy database, on their end. That database located on the same MSSQL instance has a task that copies the data in a second database, nightly.  This one, I am free to access remotely.  A user was created on MSSQL with just access to the proxy, and connection accepted just from one ip.

My scipt has to sync both ways so in my case I do a nightly 'push' the modified records from MSSQL to the crm  and 'pull' the added CRM records in the proxy DB. The intern gets notified by email of new record in proxy to update to their MSSQL app. Hope this was clear enough I realize it's hard to convey clearly in a few lines. If you have other questions feel free to ask.

Good-luck!

Comment: It is possible automate an table export in another database, and an weekly import for my db? for example? correct? the other sites don't have any Api and probably the only way that i have the access the data is just a pdf... The data is sensitive. The direct connection probably is not permitted :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the backup (gzip,zip) of the wanted part(or all) of the Database and upload it to the another Database.

Btw. cronjobs wont help you at this point, because you cant have an access to any DB from outside.

Comment: He said he doesn't want his data to be obsolete when the other is updated

Comment: cronjobs ca be used on the scripts that fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

Does the other website have an API for accessing such information?  Are they capable of constructing one? If so, that would be the best way.

Otherwise, I presume your way of getting data from their database is by directly querying it.  That can work to, just make a mysql_connect to their location and query it just like it was your own database.  Note: their db will have to be setup to work with outside connections for this method to work.